# Noise with TPA3110D2 amplifier on the same power supply as an USB HUB

Tags: noise, usb-hub, class-d

I have a TPA3110D2-based, XH-A232 amplifier board powered by a 12V switching supply (S-120W-12V). The input is the headphone output of a monitor connected to a PC.

I would like to power an USB HUB from the same power supply. However, when the HUB is powered and I connect it to any of the USB ports of the PC, a high-pitched noise appears on the speakers.

If I power the USB HUB from its own power supply, the noise goes away. If I apply a capacitor of 1uF..100uF on the input, the noise also goes away, but the sound becomes much quiter and treble is lost as well.

What could be the cause of this noise? What could be done to eliminate the noise, but still be able to power the amplifier and the HUB from the same power source.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibililties. You may benefit from 1 ohm resistor between the 12v and your amplifier, followed by the big cap aross the amplifier VVD/GND.

The switch_reg spike voltage may be so big the amplifier input transistors are driven into overload, thus acting as a mixer/down_Converter.

Also, switch_regs have input_output coupling capacitors, for EMI filtering reasons and safety reasons. These capacitors **ENSURE** trash is coupled onto the power lines, and that trash energy **WILL** find a return path, using **ALL** possible paths including thru the input wiring of your signal to the amplifier.

Comment: I have tried it with various capacitors (and I used a 1.5 ohm resistor, which probably does not make too much difference, but correct me if I am wrong), but experienced no change.

I have made some measurements and it turned out that all grounds are the same including the power and audio signal grounds, even without the amplifier connected. The audio input ground of the amplifier is connected directly to the power ground, but I am wondering if this connection could be broken, could it solve the problem? (TPA3110D2 has differential inputs.)